# Sorting a list of mixed data structures on the basis of integer value and finding an element in it based on the string value in c++?

Tags: c++, list, qt, sorting, vector

I'm programming in QtCreator and currently I'm using QList as shown in the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <QDebug>


class mixed

{

public:

    int number;
    QString name;
    QString address;
    mixed(int n, QString s, QString a)
    {
        number = n;
        name = s;
        address = a;
    }
};


bool myfunction (mixed i,mixed j) { return (i.number<j.number); }

bool mySearch (mixed i, mixed j) {
  return (i.name==j.name);
}

int main()

{

    QList<mixed>myV;
    mixed object(100, "akkas", "100");
    myV.push_back(object);
    myV.push_back(mixed(2, "akkas1", "2"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(1111, "akkas2", "1111"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(-1, "akkas3", "-1"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(7, "akkas4", "7"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(0, "akkas0", "0"));
    myV.push_back(mixed(2, "akkas0", "21"));

    for(int i=0; i<myV.size(); i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<myV.at(i).number<<" "<<myV.at(i).name<<" "<<myV.at(i).address<<endl;
    }

    std::sort (myV.begin(), myV.end(), myfunction);

    for(int i=0; i<myV.size(); i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<myV.at(i).number<<" "<<myV.at(i).name<<" "<<myV.at(i).address<<endl;
    }
//   QList<mixed>::iterator it;
//    it = std::search(myV.begin(), myV.end, object, mySearch);
//    if (it!=myV.end())
//        qDebug() << "found at position " << (it-myV.begin()) << '\n';
//      else
//      qDebug() << "not found\n";

//    qDebug()<<myV.indexOf(object)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is the commented out line

```
qDebug()<<myV.indexOf(object)<<endl;
```

fails because

```
no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'mixed' and 'const mixed')
             if (n->t() == t)
                        ^
```

On the other hand I was trying to use [std::search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/) using predicate comparison where predicate is as below:

```
bool mySearch (mixed i, mixed j) {
  return (i.name==j.name);
}
```

But I can't understand why it gives the error

```
no matching function for call to 'search(std::vector<mixed>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>, mixed&, bool (&)(mixed, mixed))'
     it = std::search(myV.begin(), myV.end, object, mySearch);
                                                            ^
```

I need to use something that can allow me easy sorting using the integer value of the mixed data type and finding any element using the string value of that type.

What mistake am I doing in my approach? What alternative do I have? Could you please give me some example with code?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

After the responses I have corrected `end` to `end()`, but even then there are errors. Now the error is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'search(QList<mixed>::iterator, QList<mixed>::iterator, mixed&, bool (&)(mixed, mixed))'
     std::search(myV.begin(), myV.end(), object, mySearch);
                                                         ^
```

Comment: read the error again: `it = std::search(myV.begin(), myV.end(), object, mySearch);` note the `myV.end` -> `myV.end()`

Comment: you dont need `myfunction` or `mysearch` as free functions, if the struct implements the corresponding operators

Comment: @tobi303: highly valued C++ professionals advise you to prefer free functions over members.  (Scott Meyers in http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)

Comment: @xtofl true, actually I my point was to implementing those functions as operators instead of introducing methods with new names. Whether as free functions or methods was actually not my point.

Answer (score 0):

```
qDebug()<<myV.indexOf(object)<<endl;
```

For this to work you need to implement == operator for class `mixed`. Example:

```
 bool operator==(const mixed& rhs)
  {
    return name == rhs.name;
  }
```

For second error, As rightly pointed out in the comments, you need to correct end iterator.

```
std::search(myV.begin(), myV.end(), object, mySearch); 
                          ^^^^^^^^
```

**UPDATE**: However this is NOT correct use of `std::search`. Use `std::search` which relies on `==` operator.

```
std::find(myV.begin(), myV.end(), object); // Uses == operator to find match
```

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

This should work.

Comment: @the_naive updated the answer, you need to use `std::find`

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, where your `find` criterion may differ from call to call, I prefer [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if):  it does not force me to overload `operator==` for my type.

```
auto it = std::find_if(begin(myVec), end(myVec),
    [](const auto &a, const auto &b) { return a.name == b.name; });

auto index = std::distance(begin(myVec), it);
```